# Modify content dependent on value

Tags: angular, angular-template

I'm working with Angular 4 and I have a problem with conditional style changing. I have a table and values in it. I need the values in a column to be changed depending if the value connected or disconnected. For example - if the value is connected, then it will display ON. If the value is disconnected it will display OFF

Here is a fragment of my code, but it doesn't work like I'd like to:

```
  <ion-note item-end>
      <span [class]="laptop.isConnected === 'true' ? 'dotOn' : 'dotOff'">{{ laptop.isConnected }}</span>
  </ion-note>
```

If the `laptop.isConnected ="true"` in the database I want to display a green circle that i already created in CSS.

Else I want to display red circle.

At the moment I can only display red circle even if it's true.

Comment: would you create an example on https://stackblitz.com/ ?. it has more situation, maybe the reason is a variable type or life hook,  etc...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<span [class.dotOn]="laptop.isConnected === 'true'"
      [class.dotOff]="laptop.isConnected !== 'true'">
  {{ laptop.isConnected }}
</span>
```

You might also want to check the contents and the type of your `laptop.isConnected` property. Is it really a string? :-)

If it was a boolean, `true === 'true'` does not hold true, hence your condition would always evaluate to the second branch.